# Prevent product A from being purchased until product B is in the cart first

Tags: cartthrob

I have two product types "standard" and "addon" these are just a custom field flag. An "addon" product can only be purchased if a "standard" product in in the cart.

How would I go about coding this up? Ideally it'd be great to have a conditional that I can run to disable the add to cart button for addon products till a standard product has been added to the cart. Soon as one standard product has been added to the cart any number of addons may be added.

I have seen [this question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2054/check-if-user-has-purchase-w-cartthrob) but it's not the same. In this case it has to be a specific *type* of product not just *any* product.

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: I would create a custom EE or Cartthrob plugin that returns a `true|false` value depending on whether the specified product is in the cart, and enable|disable the button via this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Bradley, unfortunately I wouldn't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume (hopefully correctly) you are working with logged in users at the time of purchase, so that there is a way to check if the member in question has previously purchased a standard product.

You could do this several ways I think, but here’s what jumped into my head using the regular channel entries tag and not the query tag or something more complex.

If you did a search on the Purchased Items (not orders) channel using the logged in user’s ID and `search:url_title="name-of-standard-product"` it should return all of the purchases for that user, who had already purchased a standard product, to run a comparison against.

So if the page URI that contained your standard and addon products ended with "my-product-name" and you placed the above concept into a LowVariable for example (snippets, etc. could work too), I think it would look like this.

***LowVar:***

```
{exp:channel:entries 
  channel="purchased_items" 
  status="not Closed" 
  search:author_id="{user_id}" 
  search:url_title="{url_segment}" 
  dynamic="no" 
  limit="1" 
  disable="categories|member_data|pagination"
}
 true
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

***In your template with the add to cart tags:***

```
{if '{exp:low_variables:parse var="variable-name" preparse:user_id="{logged_in_user_id}" preparse:url_segment="{url_title}"}'=='true'}
**show the add to cart for addons**
{if:else}
**You must purchase the standard product first**
{/if}
```

You could do this with javascript too of course to disable the Add to Cart buttons, but hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: Hi Derrick. Thanks for the feedback. Sorry No, the customer will NOT be logged in. I've actually just realised (it was late last night when I posted this) that the standard project only needs to be in the cart NOT purchased. Sorry for any confusion. I'll edit the question now to reflect this.